# how to find by change date in meta data

Tags: find, stat

I want to use find command to find the new file uploaded from spacific time to my server,
NOT by access time -amin
NOT by modify time -mmin

for example
I have manually upload file.ex with SFTP

```
root@server [/path-of-file]# stat file.ex
File: `file.ex'
Size: 1668            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 903h/2307d      Inode: 22820305    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2017-01-05 07:37:52.000000000 +0100
Modify: 2016-12-27 13:03:10.000000000 +0100
Change: 2017-01-05 06:48:26.000000000 +0100
```

I need to find with Change stats
which is

**Change: 2017-01-05 06:48:26.000000000 +0100**

All I want to do
find what uplaoded  file (with change stat only) from 24 hours and save output to file

Comment: Have you tried `-cmin` ?

Comment: yes try it but not return my new uploaded file

Comment: I found I have to use -[N] with cmin, this working for me find -cmin -5 for last change from 5 min .. thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're looking for the `-ctime` option. For example, `find /path -ctime -1` will find files with change time within the last 24 hours.